# Is there anyway to disable the iOS 14 "App posted from Phone" pasteboard notification if it needs to always examine content?

Tags: ios

When our app comes to the foreground it examines the contents of the pasteboard to see if it contains a phone number which the user has copied there from any other app.
If it does contain a phone number and the app has not encountered this particular phone number before then the app presents a dialog. Hence if the app finds a phone number in the clipboard it caches it, then next time it runs it examines the clipboard content again for a number and compares it to the cached value.

So in iOS 14 every time the app runs the OS is displaying a "XXX pasted from Phone" notification.

I've seen that there are supposed to be new iOS 14 apis which can be used to suppress this notification, but it seems they only surpress it if the app accesses the pasteboard metadata, but if it accesses the data then it will be displayed.

So if my app needs to read the phone number each time to see if its a new one from last time, then there's no way the notification can be suppressed?

Comment: There shouldn't be a way to avoid this on iOS 14+. This notification is shown by design as a privacy measure, so users are aware that an app is reading their clipboard information. I doubt there is any way around this

Comment: It seems like a better approach would be to provide a paste button so that the user can provide the clipboard contents if they want. The whole purpose of the new alert is to discourage apps from silently inspecting the clipboard, even if their purpose is benign.